# Communicate of USB-HID device on windows 8

Tags: .net, usb, hid

I have an embedded board with USB device port and i would like to transfer data from/to the PC at a rate of 1600Kbps.

The actual data transferred is ADC data. Basically, i  need to transfer this data to a Windows 8 machine as fast as possible.

Device side : I have a HID device  which is recognized by the windows as a HID. The HID uses one interface with 2 endpoint, a interrupt based IN endpoint (as in any HID device) which can send a 64 byte to the Windows. I have another interrupt OUT endpoint can receive 64 bytes of data. And as all USB devices i have End Point 0 to send Control transfers.

I would like to build a tool with .Net and some USB based driver. Could anybody kindly please suggest me the best library i can use for USB communication? some samples would be fine.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You might look into using [HIDAPI](http://www.signal11.us/oss/hidapi/), but in order to call it from C# you will have to define a bunch of tricky methods using PInvoke.

There is also the [HidLibrary](https://github.com/mikeobrien/HidLibrary) project for .NET but it looks unmaintained.

Comment: Thanks David for your replay.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transfer binary data over HID - you can look for approach and design that MS did in their [Component Firmware Update (CFU)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/cfu/) spec and in corresponding [example code](https://github.com/microsoft/CFU/tree/master/Tools/ComponentFirmwareUpdateStandAloneToolSample).